# How to stop DataGridView refreshing?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Here is my code. My problem is i have one datagridview vhich on selection changed generate data for another datagrid. But when this sample is executed i have refreshing on the cells. Any suggestion how to stop refreshing when another datagrid data's are generated ?`

```
      private void Refres()

    DataGridViewCell cell = dgvModeli.CurrentCell;
        if (cell != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow red = cell.OwningRow;

            ModelCosort stavka = (ModelCosort)red.DataBoundItem;

            if (stavka != null)
            {
                dgvModeli.SuspendLayout();
                normativStavki.Clear();
                // MessageBox.Show(stavka.Model);

                normativStavki = BL.BL.Stavki(stavka.Model);

            }

        //   dgvModeli.ClearSelection();
                dgvNalog.DataSource = normativStavki;
                redModeli = red;


                MessageBox.Show("NE!");
                dgvModeli.ResumeLayout();

            }                             

            OznaciSoCrveno();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your page is posting back. You'll need to put your grids inside of an ajax panel to prevent it from refreshing. When you change something in your first grid the page is posting back.

Comment: This is a windows forms application

Comment: Ok I see. You're suspending and then resuming the layout which redraws the grid. Do you need to suspend the layout at all in this case? Just load your first grid and in the event for the control that changes load the data source of the second grid in it.